# How can I rank to the top 20 combinations in a Json Array of objects using Angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, sorting

I have a Json array of objects listing pizza order toppings. I would like to use Angular to output the 20 most common order combinations of toppings and rank them from 1-20. So far I have only been able to to use a basic sample array (not my json array of objects) to output the number of occurrences in an array and output them in javascript. (A far cry I know) How can I achieve this or at least get a good start in the right direction?

Json Array of objects that I want this to work for

```
//it is much bigger than this but shortened it for brevity 
[{
        "toppings": [
            "pepperoni"
        ]
    },
    {
        "toppings": [
            "feta cheese"
        ]
    },
    {
        "toppings": [
            "pepperoni"
        ]
    },
    {
        "toppings": [
            "bacon"
        ]
    },
    {
        "toppings": [
            "sausage",
            "beef"
        ]
    }
]
```

Non json and very basic array that i've got a good start on

```
var arr = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9];

function foo(arr) {
    var a = [], b = [], prev;

    arr.sort();
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] !== prev ) {
            a.push(arr[i]);
            b.push(1);
        } else {
            b[b.length-1]++;
        }
        prev = arr[i];
    }

    return [a, b];
}

var result = foo(arr);
document.write('[' + result[0] + ']<br>[' + result[1] + ']')   
//currently writes [2,4,5,9] [5,1,3,1] 2 appears 5 times , 4 appears 1 time etc.
```

In summation I would like to have an output with Ngfor that loops through the occurrences array ie( In my 2nd example the variable letter b `[5,1,3,1]`)  and the original json array of objects ( the nested array at the top of the page ) and maps the two together to rank them from most to least. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your code to make the result like a `key value` pair :

```js
function foo(arr) {
var a = [], b = [], prev;

arr.sort();
for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    if ( arr[i] !== prev ) {
        a.push(arr[i]);
        b.push(1);
    } else {
        b[b.length-1]++;
    }
    prev = arr[i];
}
  let result = [];
  a.forEach((item,i)=>{  
        let obj = { key : item , value : b[i] }; 
        result.push(obj);   
       })
  
    return result.sort(function(a, b) {
     return  b.value - a.value;
});
   
 }

let x = [{
        "toppings": [
            "pepperoni"
        ]
    },
    {
        "toppings": [
            "feta cheese"
        ]
    },
    {
        "toppings": [
            "pepperoni"
        ]
    },
    {
        "toppings": [
            "bacon"
        ]
    },
    {
        "toppings": [
            "sausage",
            "beef"
        ]
    }
];

let obj = {"toppings" : []};
x.forEach((el)=>{
   obj.toppings = obj.toppings.concat(el.toppings);
});

var result = foo( obj.toppings);

console.log(result)
```

Now in the `component.html` file , you can iterate like below :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of result">
    <p> {{item.key}} appears {{item.value}} {{(item.value>1)? 'times' : 'time'}}
</div>
```

Here is the demo : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umhiaz)

Comment: First how do I do this for the above mentioned toppings array  (it's tricky i know because of the nested toppings elements)  and Second how do I sort the item.key and the item.value in your example from most to least occurrences?

Comment: @evan updated my answer.  you can check in stackblitz demo as well

Comment: Thanks! This does work. I'm trying to use http client in the node_modules to get this array to work by making an api to get the json. I'm not sure if you've done that before but i updated the stack blitz to reflect how it could work. Let me know what you think `private url: 'https://www.olo.com/pizzas.json'
public topps :any[] = [];

constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    http.get(this.url).subscribe(result => {
        this.topps = result as APiArray[];
    }, error => console.error(error));


interface APiArray {
   toppings: string; //? not sure about this part
 }
} `

Comment: @evan if it answers your query accept it and raise another question for a different problem

Comment: I have a question right here. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510211/im-trying-to-get-key-value-pairs-from-json-data-via-an-external-api-and-display/61510340?noredirect=1#comment108811956_61510340> I'm using angular but still trying to work with arrays. Could you help me with this?