# I'm Trying to get key value pairs from json data via an external api and display it using angular and typescript. How can I achieve this?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, observable, http-get

I would like to get each key value pair in the results object from my api to display on my front-end. ie(category, type, difficulty, questions correct_answer) I have the service and components set up correctly and all i need to do is fetch the json and display each pair. The method name is called fetchQuestions as seen below. I was able to successfully get data by just simply calling it the same way I did fetchPeople but the json format is not the same so it's not displaying. I then tried something else but that's not working either. How can I acheive displaying this?

People.service

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Observable } from  'rxjs/Observable';
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

 @Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class PeopleService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


//this works like a charm as it is just a simple array

fetchPeople(): Observable <Object> {
return this.http.get('/assets/data/people.json')
}




// this doesn't work as the json from the api below is in a different 
  // json format. Plus I need to return all value pairs

fetchQuestions(): Observable <Object> {
return this.http.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php? 
 amount=10&difficulty=hard&type=boolean').map(res => 
res.json().results).subscribe(data => {
console.log(data););
    }
  }
```

API
https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&difficulty=hard&type=boolean

```
   {
   "response_code": 0,
   "results": [
   {
   "category": "Vehicles",
   "type": "boolean",
   "difficulty": "hard",
   "question": "In 1993 Swedish car manufacturer Saab experimented 
   with replacing the steering wheel with a joystick in a Saab 9000.",
   "correct_answer": "True",
   "incorrect_answers": [
    "False"
   ]
   },
   {
  "category": "History",
  "type": "boolean",
  "difficulty": "hard",
  "question": "Japan was part of the Allied Powers during World War 
  I.",
  "correct_answer": "True",
  "incorrect_answers": [
    "False"
  ]
  },
  {
  "category": "History",
  "type": "boolean",
  "difficulty": "hard",
  "question": "The Kingdom of Prussia briefly held land in Estonia.",
  "correct_answer": "False",
  "incorrect_answers": [
    "True"
  ]
  },
  {
  "category": "Science: Mathematics",
  "type": "boolean",
  "difficulty": "hard",
  "question": "The binary number &quot;101001101&quot; is equivalent 
  to the Decimal number &quot;334&quot;",
  "correct_answer": "False",
  "incorrect_answers": [
    "True"
  ]
  },
  {
  "category": "Entertainment: Video Games",
  "type": "boolean",
  "difficulty": "hard",
  "question": "TF2: Sentry rocket damage falloff is calculated based 
 on the distance between the sentry and the enemy, not the engineer 
  and the enemy",
  "correct_answer": "False",
  "incorrect_answers": [
    "True"
  ]
 },
  {
  "category": "Entertainment: Video Games",
  "type": "boolean",
  "difficulty": "hard",
  "question": "The names of Roxas&#039;s Keyblades in Kingdom Hearts 
  are &quot;Oathkeeper&quot; and &quot;Oblivion&quot;.",
  "correct_answer": "True",
  "incorrect_answers": [
    "False"
  ]
},
{
  "category": "Entertainment: Music",
  "type": "boolean",
  "difficulty": "hard",
  "question": "The band STRFKR was also briefly known as Pyramiddd.",
  "correct_answer": "True",
  "incorrect_answers": [
    "False"
  ]
},
{
  "category": "Entertainment: Books",
  "type": "boolean",
  "difficulty": "hard",
  "question": "Harry Potter was born on July 31st, 1980.",
  "correct_answer": "True",
  "incorrect_answers": [
    "False"
  ]
},
{
  "category": "Entertainment: Japanese Anime & Manga",
  "type": "boolean",
  "difficulty": "hard",
  "question": "Druid is a mage class in &quot;Log Horizon&quot;.",
  "correct_answer": "False",
  "incorrect_answers": [
    "True"
  ]
},
{
  "category": "Geography",
  "type": "boolean",
  "difficulty": "hard",
  "question": "The two largest ethnic groups of Belgium are Flemish and Walloon. ",
  "correct_answer": "True",
  "incorrect_answers": [
    "False"
     ]
   }
 ]
}
```

People.page.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { PeopleService } from './../../providers/people.service'
 @Component({
 selector: 'app-people',
 templateUrl: './people.page.html',
 styleUrls: ['./people.page.scss'],
 })
 export class PeoplePage implements OnInit {

 people$;
 results$;
 constructor(private peopleService:PeopleService) { }

 fetchPeople(){
 this.people$ = this.peopleService.fetchPeople();
 }
 fetchQuestions(){
  this.results$ = this.peopleService.fetchQuestions()
 }




  ngOnInit() {
  }

 }
```

People.page.html

```
   <ion-toolbar>
   <ion-title>people</ion-title>
   </ion-toolbar>
   </ion-header>
   <ion-button (click) ="fetchPeople()"  color="primary">Primary</ion- 
   button>

   <ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let person of people$ | async">{{person.name}}. 
   </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
   <ion-button (click) ="fetchQuestions()"  
   color="primary">Secondary</ion-button>
   <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let result of results$ | async">. 
             {{result.category}}</ion-item>
             <ion-item *ngFor="let result of results$ | async"> 
            {{result.questions}}</ion-item>
           <ion-item *ngFor="let result of results$ | async"> 
           {{result.difficulty}}</ion-item>
           <ion-item *ngFor="let result of results$ | async"> 
            {{result.correct_answer}}</ion-item>
   </ion-list>
  <ion-content>
 <ion-button color="primary">Primary</ion-button>
 </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP GET is a cold observable. As such each `async` will fire an individual request. Besides you aren't actually returning the observable from the `fetchQuestions()` function. The subscription should be removed.

You could also use Angular [`HttpParams`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) to set the query parameters and do things the Angular way.

Try the following

Service

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

fetchQuestions(): Observable<any> {
  const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('amount', '10')
    .set('difficulty', 'hard')
    .set('type', 'boolean');  
  return this.http.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php', { params: params })
    .pipe(map(res => res.results));
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let result of results$ | async">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>{{result.category}}</ion-item>
    <ion-item>{{result.question}}</ion-item>
    <ion-item>{{result.difficulty}}</ion-item>
    <ion-item>{{result.correct_answer}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ng-container>
```

I also noticed a small type. `result.questions` should actually be `result.question`.

More details about hot vs cold observables: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kkzftr)

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try it rc/app/providers/people.service.ts:29:26 - error TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.

29     .pipe(map(res => res.json().results));

Comment: Yes in the latest versions `.json()` isn't required. Try `res => res.results`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: with the updated I'm now getting property 'results' does not exist on type 'Object'.

29     .pipe(map(res => res.results));

Comment: I changed the return type of the function to `Observable<any>` in my answer. Are you still using `Observable<Object>`? If so try with `Observable<any>`.

Comment: I'm using Observable <any>

Comment: That is probably only a TS Lint error because it doesn't have reference to the object. To solve it try `res => res['results']`.

Comment: That was the missing piece. Darn ts Lint!